# java method refactoring when multiple if statements are used

Tags: java, refactoring, java-6

How to refactor the below code when multiple if statements are used? Is there an alternate way for doing this?

```
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    if (rowData.size() > 24){
        sb.append(rowData.get(24).trim());
    }
    sb.append("|");

    if (rowData.size() > 25){
        sb.append(rowData.get(25).trim());
    }
    sb.append("|");

    if (rowData.size() > 26){
        sb.append(rowData.get(26).trim());
    }
    sb.append("|");

    if (rowData.size() > 27){
        sb.append(rowData.get(27).trim());
    }
    sb.append("|");

    if (rowData.size() > 28){
        sb.append(rowData.get(28).trim());
    }
    sb.append("|");

    if (rowData.size() > 29) {
        sb.append(rowData.get(29).trim());
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you could just use a for loop to loop over the number in the condition. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting the indexing in a loop as suggested would give you this

```
    for (int i = 24; i < 30; i++) {   
        if (rowData.size() > i){         
            sb.append(rowData.get(i).trim());
            sb.append(i <= 29 ? "|" : "");
        }
    }
```

In a more contemporary Java version also this could be done:

```
    IntStream.range(24, 29).forEach(i ->
    {            
        if (rowData.size() > i){         
            sb.append(rowData.get(i).trim());
            sb.append(i <= 29 ? "|" : "");
        }
    });
```

Comment: That will have an extra | in the beginning. Also, the upper limit of range is exclusive, so either use rangeClosed or 30.

Comment: maybe the separator is not dependent on size (always the same quantity....)